# Python; replacing substrings in a file with quoted lines

Tags: python, replace

When trying to replace substrings in a text file where each line is quoted with double quotes ("line") like this one:

```
" @user can't wait! love the orsen welles/citizen kane teaser reference in the promo vid!   positive"
```

this code doesn't work:

```
import re
with open(in_file, "r") as infile, open("Output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        #line = re.sub("@user", " ", line)        
        line = line.replace("@user"," ")
        outfile.write(line)
```

Output.txt file contains exectly the same lines as the input file. What's wrong?

*** Update-2 ***

Link to the archive where text file comes from:

```
http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~smukherjee/data/twitter-data.tar.gz
```

To get this file just save 'Manually-Annotated-Tweets.csv' to a text file.

*** Update ***

Input and output file names are different. File reads in all right. Tried several different output file names.

Configuration:

```
Server Information:

You are using Jupyter notebook.

The version of the notebook server is 4.3.1 and is running on:

Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

Current Kernel Information:

Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
```

Comment: Are you using the same filename for your input and output file?  Your code works for differently named files.

Comment: Yes, output file is different from the input, but code does not work. Output file is created with the same content as the input one. I use jupyter notebook under Windows 7 at the moment.

Comment: I ran your code, and it worked perfectly for me with `replace()`. I'm on Python 2.7.13. Can you elaborate on what exact issues you're facing? Maybe try printing intermediate outputs.

Comment: @dokondr:  My gut says you're either not reading or writing the files you think you are.  Try using the full paths to the files.

Comment: Please see updated question. Lost have a day on this.

Comment: Update-2 : link to a file in question

Comment: @dokondr:  If you print the line before and after the `replace` function, does it look like it has changed?